# JQuery event in javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript object

```
function A()
{
    this.ini = function()
    {
        $('#test').html('<button id="click" >Hi</button>');
    }    

    $('#click').on('click',function(){
        alert('Hi');
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G2MUE/1/

But I have a problem, the event onClick is not used.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The `#click` element does not yet exist when you try to bind your handler to it.

Comment: Ok I find, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920355/attaching-click-event-to-a-jquery-object-not-yet-added-to-the-dom

Comment: What are your thought behind this function? Seems kind of pointless to instantiate something with hard coded values.

Comment: Take a look at; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-on-method-not-working-on-dynamic-content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function A()
{
    this.ini = function()
    {
        $('#test').html('<button id="click" >Hi</button>');
    }    

    $(document).on('click', '#click', function(){
        alert('Hi');
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G2MUE/7/

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
$(document.body).on('click', "#click" ,function(){
    alert('Hi');
});
```

You are attaching handler before the element is in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to put it in initializeation.Try like

```
function A()
{    
    $('#test').html('<button id="click" >Hi</button>');             
    $('#click').on('click',function(){
       alert('Hi');
    });
}
A();
```

See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G2MUE/4/)

Comment: why need to down it..??Any reason

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to bind a handler to an element that doesn't exist. Try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pdT24/

```
function A() {
    this.ini = function () {
        $('<button id="click" >Hi</button>')
            .click(clickfn)
            .appendTo('#test');

    }

    var clickfn = function (e) {
        alert('Hi');
    };
}
var a = new A();
a.ini();
```

An alternative would be event delegation with `on()`:

```
$('#test').on('click', '#click', function() { ... });
```