# Function not working properly when called within onDeviceReady

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am making an app which creates some elements which links the user to another page. The code looks something like this.

```
  function showThis(){

    $('<a class="routePage"></a>').prependTo($('#updateCol')).slideDown("500",function(){}‌​)

function onDeviceReady() {
  $('.routePage').on('click',function(e){
    window.location = "page2.html";
  });
  showThis();
}
  showThis();
```

Unfortunately, only the element which was created by the `showThis()` outside the onDeviceReady will trigger the `window.location` change. For more complicated reasons, my app requires the `showThis()` to be inside the onDeviceReady function. Does anyone have a possible reason as to why this does not work?

Comment: Probably not an issue or a type, but shouldn't:

    $('<a class="routePage"    </a>').prependTo($('#updateCol')).slideDown("500",function(){});

be:

    $('<a class="routePage"></a>').prependTo($('#updateCol')).slideDown("500",function(){});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help [attaching-click-event-to-a-jquery-object-not-yet-added-to-the-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920355/attaching-click-event-to-a-jquery-object-not-yet-added-to-the-dom).  You might have to use:

```
$('body').on('click', '.routePage', function (e) {
     window.location = "page2.html";
});
```

and maybe substitute a parent element for body.

Sorry about the comment formatting:

You have this also:

```
<a class="routePage"</a>, should be <a class="routePage"></a> ?
```