# Autocomplete JQuery Form Collection Symfony

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I would like to use the jquery autocomplete function on a field of a form collection. 
For example, I have a form collection that got those fields:
name product, price.

I would like to use the autocomplete function on name product field.
The problem is that when I load the page, this field doesn't exist because it's created after I click on "add product button".
Then it will be created with this id:
invoice_products_0_name
where the number 0 is the id  of the collection.
I should use the autocomplete in all the collection.

Can you suggest me something?

Answer (score 0):

To bind DOM that is not yet created, you can use [jquery on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920355/attaching-click-event-to-a-jquery-object-not-yet-added-to-the-dom).

Add a class on your product_name input field. Then you can bind the function to the futur DOM like that

```
$('#your-form-collection').on('focus', '.input-name-autocomplete' function () {
         $(this).YourLibAutocomplete()
});
```