# Html include another Html with onclick javascript is not working after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example, Having 1st Page HTML Include header Page HTML

**Page 1 javascript**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script> 
   $(function(){
     $("#header").load("Header.html");
   });
</script>
<div id="header"></div>
```

**Header page**

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Booking
<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a id="booking" href="#">New Booking</a></li>
    <li id="cancel"><a href="url">Cancellation</a></li>
    <li id="my_booking"><a href="url">My Booking</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

So my problem is, in my header page HTML I having a menu drop-down-list. During the page is loading, I am able to click the menu to drop down the list. Once the page is complete loaded to the page 1, the menu is malfunctioned and not response after I click.

Comment: Does the dropdown menu work before trying to include it? Btw, we need the JS/jQ for the menu. Your loading function looks fine...I suspect that your menu just doesn't work in the first place.

Comment: @zer00ne it works if i put header code to the page 1. Once i separate html and include it. it will work for the first few second then not responding.

Comment: You should carry over the `<script>` tag that enables the menu. Or add event handler **after** menu is loaded.

Comment: Maybe you don't attach the event handler to the menu correctly (as it doesn't exist on DOM ready yet, because it is still being loaded asynchronously). see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10920450/2897426 => use `.on()` instead of `.click()`.

Comment: btw I wouldn't recommend using javascript for templating... there are CMS's for that (I like https://getgrav.org).

Comment: @SimonHänisch  , as you can see that i use bootstrap css with 
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Booking
This should help me to do the dropdown job. Will it because the data-toggle is not working?

Comment: @hiboss I haven't used bootstrap in a while, is the dropdown menu implemented in pure CSS or do you also include the bootstrap javascript?

Comment: @SimonHänisch yes pure CSS using the bootstrap javascript

Comment: @hiboss well pure CSS means that it doesn't need javascript to work... I just checked and that is not the case (you need javascript). So I assume you include `jquery.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` (in that order) before your own script (the one that loads the header)? I created a fiddle and use jquery's `.html('string')` to dynamically add a menu (which is basically the same as ajax loading regarding event handlers) and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/0d033by6/1/ I can't see where your difference is without seeing more of your code

Comment: also your `Header.html` markup is wrong: there is a closing `</li>` at the end that doesn't belong anywhere, and more importantly it needs to be wrapped in a `<div class="dropdown"></div>` (see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)

Answer (score 0):

You can include it by w3 simple code:

```html
<!-- mport the libraries: -->
<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>
<!-- include the page: -->
<div w3-include-html="Header.html"></div>

<script>
w3IncludeHTML();
</script>
```

[More](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

Comment: Or he can use the jQuery.ajax() method. But i think that there is another problem with his script that we are not seeing.

Comment: The comments are the problem, you cant comment like this in html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [w3-include-html](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) instead to include your `header.html`.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>

<body>

<div w3-include-html="header.html"></div>

<script>
    w3IncludeHTML();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the output of the console? Any errors?

Answer (score -2):

You probably have to wait till the document is ready.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script> 
   $(document).ready
   (
       function ()
       {
           $(function(){
               $("#header").load("Header.html");
           });
       }
   )
</script>
<div id="header"></div>
```

Comment: `$(function(){})` does that