# Jquery .click() not work if HTML element not yet added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried method :
[Attaching click event to a JQuery object not yet added to the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920355/attaching-click-event-to-a-jquery-object-not-yet-added-to-the-dom)

but seems not working in my situation. After I created `dom` elements by `jquery`, the newly created elements are not accessible. What I want is to after clicking `"click me"` button, and the image will show up and I hope click the image and a div `(#color-picker-box)` to show up.

My code: https://codepen.io/MoMoWongHK/pen/ZXbWYb

Comment: Please post your code here, users shouldn't have to go to a different site to see it

Comment: It **a simple typographical error**. `$("myDiv")` should be `$("#myDiv")` with a `#` as you are selecting by ID not by tagname.

Comment: That is a silly error...

Comment: @MoMoWongHK ... that should make you consider removing the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the number sign # when calling the id of your div,

from

```
$("myDiv").on("click" ,".color-picker-icon" , function(){
    alert("hi");
    $("#color-picker-box").removeClass("display-none");
});
```

to

```
$("#myDiv").on("click" ,".color-picker-icon" , function(){
    alert("hi");
    $("#color-picker-box").removeClass("display-none");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just missed # while using myDiv as a selector!

Wrong:

```
$("myDiv").cl....
```

Corrected:

```
$("#myDiv").cl.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event Delegation since the element is not added to dom yet. You need to capture the click on its parent.

```
$('#myDiv').on("click", "#color-picker-box", function(e){
  console.log('color box clicked');
});
```

Read more about it on:
https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ 
http://api.jquery.com/on/