# jquery draggable input cannot detect keydown / input anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am writing a draggable html div as:

[image]

And it looks like this:

[image]

But I cannot input anything like a normal input div as: `<input />`.
It does not response for any key events.

I have tried to use `stopPropagation` to stop the event to its parents as:

```
    input.onclick = function ( evt ) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        console.log( 'input got clicked' );
    };


    $( input ).on( 'keydown', function ( evt ) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        console.log( 'input got keydown' );
    } );
```

where the `input` is:

```
    let input = document.createElement( 'input' );
    input.setAttribute( 'type', 'text' );
```

and with `console.log( input )`:

[image]

but it does not help. (And for the later keydown event, no output is given in the console.)

Can anyone suggest me a way to debug this problem? It really drives me crazy. Thanks!

PS: Chrome is used.

Update: I find the problem, but do not know the reason.

It is because I decorate the parent dom as jquery draggable, and I need to cancel the `<input class='x-leaf'/>` as:

```
    $('#input-parent').draggable({
        containment: 'window',
        cancel: '.x-leaf'
    });
```

With the previous `stopPropogation` and the way suggested by @Brainfeeder, it finally works.

Comment: show us how you have defined `input` in `$( input )` looks like.

Comment: $('input') <-- needs the quotes around "input"

Comment: @Cruiser correct, unless he has defined input as a variable, and if he has, it should still be done in another way

Comment: You must be getting an error, `input in not defined`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `input` is a variable, and I have edited it in the question.

Comment: because input is created after DOM loading you better call `.on()` on a parent element that exists in DOM on page load.

Comment: instead of `$( input ).on()` use `input.on()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because input is created after DOM loading you better call .on() on a parent element that exists in DOM on page load.

```
$('#someParentEl').on( 'keydown', '.x-node input', function ( evt ) {
    console.log( 'input got keydown' );
} );
```

Comment: try changing `$(input)` to `.x-node input` or some selector matching the input instead of the object.

Comment: `  $( document ).on( 'keydown', $( '.x-node input' ), function ( evt ) {
   evt.stopPropagation();
   console.log( 'input got keydown' );
  } );`

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I have detected the event with the above code. But I still cannot input anything.

Comment: The real weird thing is that, once I add this `input.classList.add('x-connection');`, then it works, even with my previous buggy code.

Comment: `.x-connection{
 position:absolute;
 border:solid 1px #dedede;
 background-color:#2e2e2e;
 width:0.5em;
 height:0.5em;
 border-radius:0.5em;
}`

Comment: You might need to delete `evt.stopPropagation();` This keeps the data from being added to the input.

Comment: Thanks again. In the flavor of what I am doing, I add a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920355/attaching-click-event-to-a-jquery-object-not-yet-added-to-the-dom, and my preferred answer: http://jsfiddle.net/cn7y2mwb/, for people may find it useful.