# HTML Section changer with JS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to switch  once a button is pressed. This is the code. It would not be for something so simple, but I can't even get this to work.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JS Test</title>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    

    <div class="page-section page-1 active"><h1>I'm page 1</h1></div>
    <div class="page-section page-2"><h1>I'm page 2</h1></div>
    
    <button class="link link-1">Page 1 link</button>
    <button class="link link-2">Page 2 link</button>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.page-section {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
   display: none;
}
.page-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.page-2 {
  background-color: red;
}
.page-section.active {
    display: block;
}
```

JS

```
function pageActivator(page) {
    $('.page-section').removeClass('active');
    page.addClass('active');
}

$('.link').click(function() {
    var pageNum = parseInt($(this).attr('class').match(/\d+/g)[0]);
    pageActivator($('.page-' + pageNum));
});
```

This is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/StefanBobrowski/pen/PpvBdg), on the website it works, while locally it doesn't I have no idea why.
I really don't understand because the code is the same from the codepen, maybe I am missing something on the HTML file? Even if the .js file is correctly connected, I have verified it. And the CSS file too.

Comment: You're loading `app.js` in the DOM *before* any elements matching the selector `.link` are loaded into the DOM. Consequently, your `.click()` handler will not be attached to your elements properly. Move your `<script src="..."></script>` node to the end of your `<body>`.

Comment: Duplicate of [Attaching click event to a JQuery object not yet added to the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920355/attaching-click-event-to-a-jquery-object-not-yet-added-to-the-dom)

Answer (score 0):

You use `JQuery` codes but you did not call `JQuery` library. Do the following:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JS Test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```